# How do entity framework handle concurrency access,when issuing multiple delete & create opeartions

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, entity-framework-5

I have the following method inside my asp.net mvc, and i am trying to understand how will entity framework behave when multiple users access the same method :-

```
public int changeDeviceSwitch(int fromID , int toID)
        {


            var currentdevices = IT.ITSwitchPorts.Where(a => a.SwitchID == fromID);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var d in currentdevices)
            {

                tms.ITSwitchPorts.Remove(d);


                count++;

            }
            foreach (var d in currentdevices)
            {

                ITSwitchPort tsp = new ITSwitchPort() { SwitchID = toID, TechnologyID = d.TechnologyID, PortNumber = d.PortNumber };
                IT.TMSSwitchPorts.Add(tsp);

            }
            IT.SaveChanges();
            return count;
}
```

The above method, will mainly, retrieve all the records that have `switchID = fromID`, then remove all these records and add new records with new switchID.

so my question is what will happen if multiple users access the same method at the same time? as i understand that entity framework can handle the concurrent access in this way as follow:-

-userA call the method

-userB calls the same method

-userA retrieve all the records, delete, then add new records , save.

-userB retrieve all the records , delete, add new records. but when userB reach the saveChnages() , 
entity framework will raise a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when it try to delete a record that no more exists ? so is this what will happen. ?

can anyone advice please?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Entity Framework will handle multiple Delete & Create operation , if two users perform the same transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827059/how-entity-framework-will-handle-multiple-delete-create-operation-if-two-use)

Comment: @GertArnold please read the two questions , to realize that they are talking about two different cases, while the title might be similar but the case is totally different ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General approach to locking in EF is to use Optimistic locking.
[EF Locking docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904)
[SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718991/1347784)

> -userB retrieve all the records , delete, add new records. but when userB reach the saveChnages() , entity framework will raise a
>   DbUpdateConcurrencyException when it try to delete a record that no
>   more exists ? so is this what will happen. ?

Yes this is what will happen IF you have declared a Concurrency field on the record.
eg

```
 public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in my case the ITSwitchPort table do NOT have a timestamp field nor i have include a rowversion. so that why i need to understand how did EF know that a concurrent conflict happened, and it raised the DbUpdateConcurrencyException...

Comment: could the reason be that when EF mark an object for deletion , then if it find that the object no more exists (because it was deleted by another user) it will raise a dbupdateexception ? and this what happen in my situation ?

Comment: If you dont have a concurrency field, then EF must be throwing the exception on Remove when the key is not longer found. Based on the EF approach, Load Context then set state as "deleted".