# I need to do rollback or somenthing when I don't need to do anything more?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, transactionscope

I have this method that return a bool:

```
using(Entities dbContext = new Entities())
{
    using (DbContextTransaction myTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //Get data from database

        //check data from database

        //if my data is the expected: return true;
            //???: rollback or something to do or is it enough with the return?


        //if not is expected:
            //update data;
            //dbContext.Savechages();
            //myTransaction.Commit();
            //return true;
    }
}
```

My doubt is, if I don't have to do more with the data, is it enough returning true or It would be recommended to do a rollback, or commit with no SaveChanges?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are reading the data and doing nothing to it, then you do not need to rollback since there is nothing to rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your data before begin transaction, you dont need begin trasnaction while you are reading data from DB, because first part in your logic there is no any update,insert... and you dont need any commit or rollback

Actually your code should be like this

```
using(Entities dbContext = new Entities())
{
        //Get data from database

        //check data from database

        //if my data is the expected: return true;

using (DbContextTransaction myTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
         //if not is expected:
            try 
             {
               //update data;
               //dbContext.Savechages();
               //myTransaction.Commit();
               //return true;
             }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
            transaction.Rollback();
            ......
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I open the transaction after check the data, another user could modify the data and when I open the transaction I can't be sure that the data has the expected values. If i use the transaction it is to ensure that.

Comment: begin transaction cant lock your table or table row, if you are in begin trasaction block that time  another user can change data in your database, there is no any lock, Try to lock row , or check your row status was it changed or no... you can use "RowVersion"  like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718929/best-practice-to-lock-a-record-for-editing-while-using-entity-framework

Comment: Yes, in my example for simplify, I dind't explain that in my case I want to use pesimistic concurrency. But with EF, if I don't block the rows with hits like UPDLOCK, there is no reason to use a transaction, from my point of view, because dbContext is a transaction.